# MS Access: How do I find an employee with the latest date with "Working" or "Reinstated" status only?

Tags: sql, ms-access

tbl_emp_mast

```
emp_no emp_last_name emp_first_name
1      smith          john
2      doe            jane
3      case           justin
```

tbl_emp_st

```
emp_no  st_date      emp_st
1       10/01/2020    WORKING
1       10/05/2020    QUIT
1       10/10/2020    REINSTATED
2       10/07/2020    QUIT
3       10/02/2020    WORKING
```

For the purpose of the combo box in the form, I wanted only those employees who are currently working. So, there should be employees # 1 and 3 from  the query result.
I tried this:

```
SELECT tbl_emp_mast.emp_no AS tbl_emp_mast_emp_no, tbl_emp_mast.emp_last_name & ", " & tbl_emp_mast.emp_first_name AS Employee, tbl_emp_st.st_date, tbl_emp_st.emp_st
FROM tbl_emp_mast INNER JOIN tbl_emp_st ON tbl_emp_mast.[emp_no] = tbl_emp_st.[emp_no];
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the logic for someone currently working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I think you want the most recent `emp_st`.  If so, then I think:

```
select es.*
from tbl_emp_st as es
where es.st_date = (select max(es2.st_date)
                    from tbl_emp_st as es2
                    where es2.emp_no = es.emp_no
                   ) and
      es.emp_st in ('WORKING', 'REINSTATED');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a WHERE clause to check that the latest date for each `tbl_emp_st` is a row where `emp_st` is not equal to `'QUIT'`:

```
SELECT m.emp_no AS tbl_emp_mast_emp_no, 
       m.emp_last_name & ', ' & m.emp_first_name AS Employee, 
       s.st_date, 
       s.emp_st
FROM tbl_emp_mast AS m INNER JOIN tbl_emp_st AS s
ON m.emp_no = s.emp_no
WHERE s.st_date = (SELECT MAX(st_date) FROM tbl_emp_st WHERE emp_no = m.emp_no)
    AND s.emp_st <> 'QUIT'
```

Results:

```
tbl_emp_mast_emp_no   Employee        st_date       emp_st
1                     smith, john     10/10/2020    REINSTATED
3                     case, justin    10/02/2020    WORKING
```